# Matching at least 1 of 2 values of an array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got an array [1,2,3,4,5] as a field value
and I'd to calculate the sum of all fields where the array either contains 1 or 2

ex:

```
array [2,3,4,5,6]
2

array [2,1,3]
1,2

array [5,8,9]
false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Arrays_Overlap()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/arrays_overlap.html) is a super efficient function - way faster than checking things one by one.

[image]

```
-- SET UP PLAY RAYS
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT  [1,2,3,4,5]  RAY UNION ALL SELECT [10,20,30,40,50] UNION 
ALL SELECT  [1,2,3,4,5] )
SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM CTE,TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT=>RAY)) WHERE ARRAYS_OVERLAP([1,2], RAY)
```